# Actioncable with Active Jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

Has anyone tried actioncable with active job with an adaptor other than async?

When I use active job(with sidekiq) to broadcast messages to clients it does not send data to any of the clients. This makes sense also because sidekiq is running as another process and doesn't have connections to Action cable clients.

When I switch to active job with async adaptor it works which also makes sense because the jobs are run by Puma.

Any idea how can we use Sidekiq or any adaptor can be used to read jobs from redis and send messages to all connected clients?

Thanks

Comment: If anyone has find an alternative to redis , i'm also interested . Heroku wants a credit card for addon (i dont have one :(    )

Answer (score 1):

well, it's can be late, but i solve this using redis on actioncable
in cable.yml

```
adapter: redis
```